# Azure AD Authentication with SharePoint 2013 Not Working

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to establish authentication using Azure AD within a SharePoint 2013 site.

I followed the instructions in the article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn635311(v=office.15).aspx).

It looks like everything has been setup correctly.  When I navigate to the SharePoint site, I am presented with a drop down to select the authentication provider.  If I choose the AAD provider, I can enter my credentials.  However, at this point, I am returned to the sign in page.  From here the process repeats.

The really strange thing is I have seen it actually work a time or two.

Since I am not *technically* getting any errors, I am not sure how to troubleshoot this one.

Any suggestions or ideas as to what to look at?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I used Fiddler to see what the issue was. I was able to find out that it was a certificate related error, as I was using a self signed cert that was not configured correctly. I ended up switching to a wildcard certificate that we owned and it fixed the looping sign in page.